# How to append parenthesis if a specific condition satisfies in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have below query which gives me output like `-$97.90` or `$11.00`

```
Select TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99')) as PenAmount
from transact;
```

Now, if the value starts with `-`, I want to remove `-` and encapsulate the same as `($97.90)`. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see how you get the `$` from that code.

Comment: @mathguy Oops, updated

Comment: `Does Select TRIM(to_char(ABS(pen_amt),'$999,999,999,999,999.99')) as PenAmount from transact;` give you what you need?

Comment: @JerryM., It removes `-`, but does not enclose the value inside parenthesis. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also using the PR format model element, which surrounds positive (and zero) values with single spaces and negative numbers with angled brackets:  You can follow that up with the TRANSLATE function if you really need the format you requested. (Notice that if I use TRANSLATE, I don't need to use TRIM, or the format model modifier FM in TO_CHAR, which would do the same thing; I can simply remove the spaces with TRANSLATE.)

```
with
  test_data (amount) as (
    select  320.88 from dual union all
    select -309    from dual
  )
select amount, 
       to_char(amount, '$999,999,999.99pr') as pr_formatted_amount,
       translate(to_char(amount, '$999,999,999.99pr'), '<> ', '()')
                                            as my_formatted_amount
from   test_data
;

    AMOUNT PR_FORMATTED_AMOUNT MY_FORMATTED_AMOUNT
---------- ------------------- -------------------
    320.88            $320.88  $320.88          
      -309           <$309.00> ($309.00)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement to check if the value starts with `-`:

```
Select 
  case when TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99')) like '-%'
    then '(' || substr(TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99')), 2) || ')'
    else TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99'))  
  end as PenAmount 
from transact;
```

Or by directly checking if pen_amt is negative:

```
Select 
  case when pen_amt < 0
    then '(' || TRIM(to_char(abs(pen_amt),'$999,999,999,999,999.99')) || ')'
    else TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99'))  
  end as PenAmount 
from transact;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use  <> brackets then PR will do the trick.

```
Select TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'$999,999,999,999,999.99PR')) as PenAmount from transact;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `PR` in the mask along with `TRANSLATE` to convert angle brackets to parentheses.

```
Select translate(to_char(-12345.6789,'FM$999,999,999,999,999.99PR'),'<>','()') as PenAmount from dual;

Select translate(to_char(23456.789,'FM$999,999,999,999,999.99PR'),'<>','()') as PenAmount from dual;
```

> ($12,345.68)
>
> $23,456.79

The `PR` mask puts angle brackets for negative numbers.

The `FM` mask tells Oracle to show the minimal text (i.e. TRIM it).